# Java Maven project won't compile properly(consistently) when running on Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I have a Java Maven project that compiles and works just fine on my local machine. However when I try to run from Jenkins, it fails miserably with a bunch of bizarre errors. It won't even compile complaining that one of the method constructors can't accept the current set of arguments which it definitely can and works that way perfectly on my local machine.

I tried to update Maven plug-in for Jenkins, restart it but frankly, I don't have a slightest idea what could possibly go wrong?

I will be happy to hear ANY theories of what could go wrong and how a working project can't even be complied all of a sudden.

I realize that the description is a bit vague but didn't want post garbage but happy to share any additional info if required.

**Example**:

Below you can find and example of the error code. Generally `cannot find symbol` error means that compiler doesn't understand what this expression is. But please mind that these errors have nothing to do with the correctness of the original code as it works fine locally. Moreover, I found that **committing meaningless space symbols sometimes helps and the build successfully completes**! These errors might vary as well.

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] C:\.jenkins\path\ParseResultsTest.java:[113,44] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method getScenarios()
  location: variable ffe of type FeatureFileElement
C:\.jenkins\path\ParseResultsTest.java:[114,93] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method getRunResult()
  location: variable scenario of type Scenario
C:\.jenkins\path\ParseResultsTest.java:[203,42] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method getScenarioName()
  location: variable scenario of type Scenario
C:\.jenkins\path\ParseResultsTest.java:[210,68] error: cannot find symbol
[INFO] 4 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.704 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-08-11T15:06:26+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/190M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: There are many reasons for failure- Please add exception logs, error messages etc question.

Comment: are you uploading the project properly ? or simply override the previous version? cause this looks like java src sources are missing/merged

Comment: @AntJavaDev The project is on Github and Jenkins loads the last version each time.

Comment: @Jayan I added an example and more information. Thanks.

Comment: so you can see , f.e. the src for getScenarioName() and its updated?

Comment: @AntJavaDev yes, the code is definitely getting updated properly and being copied each time I trigger the build on Jenkins server.

Comment: hmm , have you set character encoding in project's main pom?

Comment: @AntJavaDev yes, that was one of my guesses too, so I manually set UTF-8 in my POM.

Comment: hope that you are using same java versions ..... ?

Comment: @AntJavaDev yes, I do :) BTW, now I just built it few times in a row and sometimes it says that one of the methods does not exist and the other time it worked fine. I'm going crazy with that.

Comment: hmmm ,  i have no clue what's happening , as a last advice try to check jenkins settings for the local/remote repo , any configuration that might disrupts the src packages and if you can check in the system that jenkins is up , the local configuration there , java version ,maven version, default character encoding and if you have access to the system through a console , try to build it manually , so if it builds it will be a jenkins issue

Answer (score 0):

Checkpoints from my experience

1. java version mentioned in maven and Jenkins should be same
2. Repository used by maven in both local and jenkins should be same and Jenkins should able to access the repository

Comment: Not to forget: Maven version should also be the same and best practice defining all plugins which are used.